# Are there any cases of infinitives being used as a "patient nominal"?

Tags: syntax, infinitive, nominals

Usually, when infinitives are used in the nominal position, they denote a situation, but I never met any languages that use infinitives to denote participants. The only exception is German "Essen", but it is the only case I know. If you heard of such languages where the conversion from infinitive to "patient nominal" is productive, I would be very thankful

Comment: Not the most productive, but English has a tendency to use a gerund in -ing to mean the result of the action: a painting is painted, a building is built, etc.

Comment: What about English, where there are many words where a concrete noun and a related infinitive (without "to") have the same form: "drink," "step," "fence," "bus," "partner," etc.?